# Deploying An Application that Uses microsoft.crm.sdk web service

Tags: web-services, dynamics-crm

I have used web services in the past and nothing special was required for deployment. As long as the application compiled and you could get to it through Visual Studio all was well. I am integrating a custom application with Microsoft Dynamics CRM and am receiving an error when I deploy the application as follows: Could not load file or assembly 'microsoft.crm.sdk' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.

I don't know if this is a CRM issue or a web service issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bitness issue. The CRM SDK DLLs exist in 32- and 64-Bit versions, and you need to use the correct DLL for the bitness you are using for your project.

Comment: Any idea where the 64-bit version lives? Everything I find (ex. http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/confirmation.aspx?FamilyID=420F0F05-C226-4194-B7E1-F23CEAA83B69) is 32-bit.

Comment: Nevermind. 64-bit dlls are included too. http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyId=82E632A7-FAF9-41E0-8EC1-A2662AAE9DFB&displaylang=en

Answer (score 0):

Yes I also found that ...

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsazure/thread/344034f9-4d14-401f-b230-cb25fbd9914d